# Как бот телеграмма может от пользователя получить номер телефона и местоположение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Хочется сделать отправку контакта и местоположения, например, через кнопки на `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`.

Минимальный пример:

```
# pip install python-telegram-bot
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

import config

...

def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.message

    message.reply_text(
        'Echo: ' + message.text
    )


def main():
    updater = Updater(
        config.TOKEN,
        use_context=True
    )

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', on_start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_request))
    
    updater.start_polling()
    
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно:

- Создать `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` добавив кнопки с специальными атрибутами:

  - `request_location=True` и `request_contact=True`
- Добавить обработчики для:

  - `Filters.contact` и `Filters.location`
- В обработчиках контракт или геопозицию можно получить из полей:

  - `update.message.contact` и `update.message.location`

Тогда, при клике на одну из кнопок, клиент запросит разрешение на отправку и бот получит данные.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e8c3c982ab2d873240fd9d89e54c6d8dea682169/telegram_bot_examples/send_contact_or_location.py#L50)

```
# pip install python-telegram-bot
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

import config


contact_keyboard = KeyboardButton('Send contact', request_contact=True)
location_keyboard = KeyboardButton('Send location', request_location=True)
custom_keyboard = [[contact_keyboard, location_keyboard]]
REPLY_KEYBOARD_MARKUP = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard)

...

def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.message

    message.reply_text(
        'Echo: ' + message.text,
        reply_markup=REPLY_KEYBOARD_MARKUP
    )


def on_contact_or_location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.message

    text = ''
    if message.contact:
        text += str(message.contact)

    if message.location:
        text += str(message.location)

    message.reply_text(
        text,
        reply_markup=REPLY_KEYBOARD_MARKUP
    )


def main():
    updater = Updater(
        config.TOKEN,
        use_context=True
    )

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', on_start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_request))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.contact | Filters.location, on_contact_or_location))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```